# FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder hyperlink code navigation and f3 open declaration problem

Tags: flexbuilder, flash-builder

I am having an issue in FB4 where some classes are not accessible through hyperlink navigation (Command-Space) or Open Declaration (F3). The classes ARE available through Open Resource (Shift-Command-R) and the project compiles fine when I use them.

What's especially strange is that only SOME of the classes in each packager are available, but some are not. And the same holds true for auto-complete, i.e. if I begin an import statement, not all of the classes will not be available for auto-complete.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

-Gabriel

http://www.pizmogames.com

Answer (score 0):

Making a change to every .as file in my project fixes this -- but only until the next time I open the project. So, now I have to make a batch change of some kind (appending a return, etc) to all my .as files (unix touch is not enough,... the contents much change) each time I open it. I wish there was a better solution.